# Comparing two void* vs. two uintptr_t

Tags: c++, c++20, libstdc++

In the following piece of code (implementation of `std::compare_three_way` in [libstc++](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/16e2427f50c208dfe07d07f18009969502c25dc8/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/libsupc%2B%2B/compare#L495)), what is the rationale behind the two `reinterpret_cast<__UINTPTR_TYPE__>`?

```
if constexpr (__detail::__3way_builtin_ptr_cmp<_Tp, _Up>)
  {
    auto __pt = static_cast<const volatile void*>(__t);
    auto __pu = static_cast<const volatile void*>(__u);
    if (__builtin_is_constant_evaluated())
      return __pt <=> __pu;
    auto __it = reinterpret_cast<__UINTPTR_TYPE__>(__pt);
    auto __iu = reinterpret_cast<__UINTPTR_TYPE__>(__pu);
    return __it <=> __iu;
  }
else
  return static_cast<_Tp&&>(__t) <=> static_cast<_Up&&>(__u);
  }
```

Why is the `void*` comparison fine in constant evaluated context, but not in runtime context? I know that `reinterpret_cast` is not a constant expression, but why is the `reinterpret_cast` necessary at all?

Comment: My guess is that it results in better codegen in some cases. But I have no idea why that might be. Also note that it’s UB to compare pointers from different objects (i.e. not belonging in the same array) but I don’t think that the standard library implementation would worry about that.

Comment: @KonradRudolph It's not like `reinterpret_cast`ing would make the UB issues from comparing pointers magically go away. I also don't see how it would influence codegen... maybe it avoids compiler warnings?

Comment: @G.Sliepen (1) What do you mean? Comparing two `uintptr_t`s is always legal (there are no restrictions), and the casts are legal too. Therefore, in situations where `__pt` and `__pu` point into different objects, casting them to `uintptr_t` before comparing would make the code well-defined. (2) UB often influences codegen (but like I said, I don’t see how it would do that here).

Comment: @G.Sliepen It seems it does neither affect codegen nor warnings, at least on gcc: https://godbolt.org/z/YPjY8zf7h

Comment: @KonradRudolph Legal, yes. But consider that if there is no guaranteed strict ordering for pointers unless they point to the same object or array of objects, what does that mean for the result of the comparison after casting to `uintptr_t`?

Comment: @G.Sliepen Right, but that's not what you said. You said that it doesn't magically make UB go away, but it does. Whether the result is usable is *implementation* defined, not UB.